# Running a .sql file in VS Code using mssql extension - not executing when file saved to git versioned network folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, sql-server-2016

I'm using VS Code with the `mssql` extension - both installed this week so up-to-date.

I can connect to our sql-server.

I then right-click the database name and select 'New Query' and do the following:

```
SELECT 1
```

I then save the file onto a network drive, re-run the script and all is still good.

I then save the file into a git versioned folder and this now happens:

[image]

It does not return a result - the query cannot be cancelled from within Code and I need to close the application. Moreover any .sql files I have saved in this git versioned directory are not usable from within Code.

Anyone any ideas what is happening and how to solve it?

---

Edit the git directory is cloned and synced from an Azure DevOps Repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure why the following works and there are likely other solutions.

I deleted my local Repo.

Then in Azure DevOps I cloned the repo using the "Clone to VS" option.

The SQL scripts now execute fine.